# Pandas Invert Sign for Selected Index

Tags: python, pandas

In my data below referring to the index, Revenue is in positive values, while the Costs i.e. Direct Cost, Manpower, Supplies & Material, Other Operating Cost are in negative values following finance convention.

[image: Sample Data]

How can I transform the data so that:

- Revenue row is unchanged
- Other rows will have their values inverted i.e. multiply by -1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all rows where is necessary multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
cols = df.index.difference(['Revenue'])
df.loc[cols] = df.loc[cols].mul(-1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[-4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,-8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,-5],
                   'E':[5,-3,6],
                   'F':[-7,4,3]}, 
                   index=['Revenue', 'Direct Cost','Manpower'])

print (df)
             A  B  C  D  E  F
Revenue      1 -4  7  1  5 -7
Direct Cost  2  5 -8  3 -3  4
Manpower     3  6  9 -5  6  3

cols = df.index.difference(['Revenue'])
df.loc[cols] = df.loc[cols].mul(-1)
print (df)
             A  B  C  D  E  F
Revenue      1 -4  7  1  5 -7
Direct Cost -2 -5  8 -3  3 -4
Manpower    -3 -6 -9  5 -6 -3
```

Another solution is created `Series` for multiple with [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) + [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = (df.index.to_series() == 'Revenue').map({True:1, False:-1})
print (s)
Revenue        1
Direct Cost   -1
Manpower      -1
dtype: int64

df = df.mul(s, axis=0)
print (df)
             A  B  C  D  E  F
Revenue      1 -4  7  1  5 -7
Direct Cost -2 -5  8 -3  3 -4
Manpower    -3 -6 -9  5 -6 -3
```

Or simplier use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for convert array by mask with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df = df.mul(np.where(df.index == 'Revenue', 1, -1), axis=0)
print (df)
             A  B  C  D  E  F
Revenue      1 -4  7  1  5 -7
Direct Cost -2 -5  8 -3  3 -4
Manpower    -3 -6 -9  5 -6 -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @jezrael's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[-4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,-8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,-5],
                   'E':[5,-3,6],
                   'F':[-7,4,3]}, 
                   index=['Revenue', 'Direct Cost','Manpower'])
```

Build an array of `-1`/`+1` from a boolean array.  Operate directly on the underlying `values` array.  This is very fast.

When the the index value is `Revenue` we get a `True`, otherwise `False`.  Multiply that by `2` and we get `2` when equal to `Revenue`, otherwise `0`.  Subtract `1` and we get `1` when `Revenue` otherwise `-1`.  Now we just need to multiply this by each column in the values array.  We use numpy broadcasting.  In order to broadcast, we turn our 1d-array of `-1` and `1` to a n x 1 array with `[:, None]`.  Now we can multiply every column.

```
df.values[:] *= ((df.index.values == 'Revenue') * 2 - 1)[:, None]
df

             A  B  C  D  E  F
Revenue      1 -4  7  1  5 -7
Direct Cost -2 -5  8 -3  3 -4
Manpower    -3 -6 -9  5 -6 -3
```